# Can someone point me the Sutra that explains the fall of Human civilization?

Tags: reference-request, sutras

There is a sutra about the downfall of our civilization. It explains how some people flee the urban life and live in far away places while others go into a Killing spree/ War. It also features how the people who fled come to their senses and how they build a proper society again. This is a Sutra in Sutra pitaka (Theravada).

Can someone name this and give me a link?

Answer (score 2):

This is found in [Cakka,vatti Siha,nāda Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/36.10-Cakkavatti-Sihanada-S-d26-piya.pdf)

Comment: The bit quoted by the OP (about "fleeing") might be, "What now if we enter the thick grass, (etc.)" in verse 21.2 on page 42